# Created Image from running instance.Now the instance not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-ami

I have created an image from a running instance which had a web application/service running in it.But after I did this the webservice is not working,though the running instance is fine and health checks are ok.What would have happened while I made the image?Please help

Comment: Did you have any EBS volume attached to the image where the application had some files? The best bet is to check the application logs as the instance itself is running OK.

Comment: I meant EBS to instance not image

Answer (score 0):

When you create an image from a running EC2 instance, it will reboot by default unless you specify the "No Reboot" option.  This will have interrupted your web service, depending on how you've configured it to recover from reboots.

Comment: I have created the instance with its default settings.Is there anyway I can restore the service

Comment: Not the instance, the actual service that you're having trouble with.  It may not be configured to start automatically.

Comment: Best strategy is to stop the instance first then take an AMI.